# StreamSets - How to call Call JDBC Query Executed after the JDBC producer

Tags: sql, etl, streamsets

I am building a pipeline where I am loading data from Kafka consumer stage to JDBC producer (SQL Server). After this insertion I want to run one stored procedure which has some logic applied on the inserted data however I am not seeing **option to connect stage (JDBC Query) after the JDBC Producer destination**. Can you guys please help me here?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a stored procedure on the database itself? Why do you need Streamsets to trigger that?

Comment: Actually from Kafka consumer I will have around 200 records loaded in a batch, after that I want to call stored procedure which pick those 200 records from loaded table, and do the joins, transformations and then will load into another table. I want to trigger SP from streamsets because I want that SP to execute for that particular batch only

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Streamsets, but I don't think the SQL actions pass batches; each record forms its own query